# Jquery not returning elements included via PHP require() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have several long list in my index page, so I decided to create them once in a PHP document and include them in the main index page wherever necessary using PHP require() function. The problem is Jquery isn’t returning the list items in the list, its returning the number of list item in the list.

Code inside index.php:

```
<ul class="some-list">
    <?php require("list.php"); ?>
</ul>
```

Code inside list.php:

```
<li>Element 1</li>
<li>Element 2</li>
<li>Element 3</li>
<li>Element 4</li>
<li>Element 5</li>
```

I’m not echoing the html code, just want the content of list.php in place of require()

The Jquery code:

```
$('.some-list').children();
```

OR

```
$('.some-list').find('li');
```

Both doesn’t work

Here’s what I’m getting in the console

```
$('.some-list ').find('li');
> v.fn.v.init[191]
```

If I include the list items inside index.php i.e. not including it through PHP, everything works fine.

Jquery version I’m using is 1.8.3

Am I missing something? Please help me on this.

Comment: *"The problem is Jquery isn’t returning the list items in the list, its returning the number of list item in the list."* are you sure? php won't change the fact that .find returns a jQuery collection. View the source of the page (ctrl+u) and find the list. That's what jquery can see. If the list is empty, that's where your problem lies. Fix that before you start worrying about how jQuery interprets things.

Comment: Checked the source, all the list item exists as it should be. Still not able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your script executing before the page loads. You need to execute your jQuery AFTER the page elements have been built.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some-list').find('li').each(function() {
      console.log($(this));
    });
  });
</script>
<ul class="some-list">
    <?php require('list.php'); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to surround file you require with quotes, ex:

```
<?php require("list.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the quotes here, my bad, but I'm already using quotes in my php file, still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Change your PHP code to:

```
<ul class="some-list">
    <?php include "list.php"; ?>
</ul>
```

And wrap your jQuery code in:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some-list').find('li');
  });
</script>
```